# How to convert a global script into a function?

Tags: php, global-variables, fatal-error

Hi guys i'm having a small issue when i try and convert my exisiting script into a simple function. I'll leave my code below.

**PHP:**

```
function service_check($postcode) {
    $op_postcodes = array(... "DG10","DG3","DG4" ...);

    if(isset(htmlentities($postcode))) {
        $postcode_checker = trim(strtoupper(htmlentities($postcode)));
        $trim_postcode = trim(substr(htmlentities($postcode_checker, 0, -3)));

        if(empty($postcode_checker)) {
            $error = "We require your postcode to check our service in your area.";
        } else if(!valid_postcode($postcode_checker)) {
            $otp = "The postcode you entered is invalid.";
        } else if(!in_array($trim_postcode, $op_postcodes)) {
            $otp = "Sorry, but we don't provide our service's in your area, just yet.";
        } else {
            $otp = "Great news! We're in your area and you are eligible to order our services!";
            $_SESSION['customer_postcode'] = $postcode_checker;
        }
    } else {
        $otp = "To get started please enter your postcode.";
    }
}
```

My current usage of the function is `<?php service_check($_POST['service_check']); ?>`

My error is:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in /home/domain.com/public_html/controller/application/functions/locale.SM.php on line 27

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Any errors? What is the output?

Comment: Sorry for being so vague _Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in /home/domain.com/public_html/controller/application/functions/locale.SM.php on line 27_

Comment: @RRAWebteam: Please edit your question to be more complete.  New viewers may not spend the time to read through the comments, and the question should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: Also, the error seems kinda, well, self explanatory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
 if(isset(htmlentities($postcode))) {
```

to this

```
$pc = htmlentities($postcode);
if(isset($pc)) {
```

read this if you get sometime - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Since your questions wasn't complete i assume so now an edit. The better approach could be to use !empty() instead of isset() on our if condition.

Even better, reove htmlentities method call from your if block and then later use html entities when you actually need it.